# Outgoing traffic using Local(internal) PC IP address to a DDNS hostname

Tags: networking, dns, ip, tcp, hostname

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I have two devices connected through the internet.
I need device A (Windows Server 2012) to send data down to device B, but unfortunately device B does not have a static WAN IP address but does have a DDNS hostname. To make things worse the program which will be used to transmit the data only accepts IP addresses.

There is no active user interaction to enter the IP address each time. Instead the IP addresses will be configured into the program and data will be sent as and when required by the program.

What are the possible solutions to overcome this issue?

My thoughts:

- DNS servers are used to translate hostnames to IP addresses and vice versa so they are a possible solution, but I am not sure how to configure the PC to allow it to use the IP addresses in such a way. (I know how to configure a DNS server to point an IP address to a domain name). And also I need to know how to configure the DNS server to be ONLY for internal IP to hostname resolution within the same PC/Server.
- A reverse proxy server. This is another possibility. But I have not played with proxy servers and I am not sure if I can host and run a proxy server internally only.

I really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: **1)** What operating system is installed on the device A? **2)** Do you have to manually enter the destination IP address or there is some sort of config file or an automated interface, API, etc. that the program uses to configure itself? In other words - do you have to manually interact with the program in order to set the IP address?

Comment: Added answers to original question.
1) Windows for Device A, an embeded OS on Device B
2) IP addresses will be configured manually, and subsequently no further interaction is required.

Comment: Thank you for answers. Can you also tell what protocol is used by this program? Is it TCP or UDP?

Comment: Most likely TCP.
Any clues to how best to tackle this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not provide detailed solution, but generally speaking you can try running a SOCKS proxy server which will receive traffic for device B and (hopefully) resolve its DDNS name and route the traffic. There is only one question - how to route traffic from your program to the SOCKS server. I don't know if your app can send it directly to the proxy or traffic will have to be rerouted on device A. I can not provide more details, but you also can try to search for 'SOCKS proxy server' and I am pretty sure you will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay  Will look into SOCKS proxy servers. If I manage to solve the issue I will post back here. Thanks again!